# WordPress max upload filesize not respecting php.ini

Tags: wordpress

My php.ini is set to 128M upload: http://nexus33.com/phpinfo.php

However WP Media Manager is only allowing a 8MB upload. I have tried disabling all plugins, checking for any php.ini files in my web root (none), regenerating my PHP configs in WHM (I have root access) and so on.

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the post_max_size to 128M as well!